# How to get configured email account details

Tags: email, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to get all email ids, that are configured on wp7 device, using outlook or mail client?
I'm looking at APIs provide my ms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428753(v=VS.92).aspx

But couldn't find anything useful, if not API, are there any alternate ways to findout?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. See MSDN on [UserExtendedProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.userextendedproperties.trygetvalue%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) , which is all the information about the user you can get.

> In the current release the only supported property is “ANID”.